# meaning of "tab him"

Tags: word-meaning

What does "tab him" mean in the animated TV series Dastardly and Muttley?

```
Mutley, you snickering, floppy eared hound.
When courage is needed, you're never around.
Those medals you wear on your moth-eaten chest
Should be there for bungling at which you are best.

So, stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Stop that pigeon
Howwww!

Nab him
Jab him
Tab him
Grab him
Stop that pigeon now.
```

Source: Soundtrack Artists - Dastardly & Mutley In Their Flying Machine Lyrics | MetroLyrics

[image]

**-- My answer that I have deleted --**

I think I knew the answer!
Even though I am not given to posting answers, I am forced to post one after taking sometime to prepare the question.

It sounds as if Dastardly doesn't mind that pigeon gets hit and stuck to a wall for example.

From Oxford Dictionaries Site

verb (tabs, tabbing, tabbed) [with object]

***Mark*** or identify with a projecting piece of material:

> he opened the book at a page tabbed by a cloth bookmark
>
> His copy of The Diviners was meticulously tabbed and flagged and he
>   had a thick file of all of the emails that the two men had exchanged
>   with each other before this evening.

Comment: Ehh...maybe.  "Tabbed" is really only used for paper documents.  The concept is that a book has lots of pages, the edges of which line up perfectly, and a little tab sticks out so the page it marks can easily be found. Do they want to mark the pigeon so it can be easily found in the future?  Even if it were the case, they would "tag" it, not "tab" it.
Neither _tab_ nor _tab_ really makes sense in this context. Here they clearly want to capture the pigeon using any means possible. I think word was chosen because it rhymes.  Cartoons don't always worry too much about meaning.

Comment: Whoops - that should read: Neither tab nor **tag** really makes sense in this context.

Comment: Have you given deeper thoughts to this example from the definition above Adam "he opened the book at a page tabbed by a **cloth** bookmark"? Wouldn't they capture the pigeon in a way similar to that cloth between the two ends of the book?

Comment: Maybe it's this **[tab](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tab_15)**: "to choose someone for a particular job, responsibility, or honor; *Even from his early days, he was tabbed as a future leader.*"

Comment: I guess a word was chosen that rhymes with *nab, jab, grab.* I think *tab* could very well mean 'to single out' or to identify' the pigeon. On the other hand, does it matter what it means? I mean if the word were a nonsense word that rhymed, such as *dlab,* wouldn't that be okay for a kids book or for some goofy dastard character to say?

Comment: @learner _Tabbing_ the book doesn't mean opening the page to a certain tab.  It means placing small tabs in the book so you can easily find a page in the future.  I don't see how either idea can possibly refer to a method for catching a pigeon.  It is a nonsense word that rhymes.

Comment: Singling out seems to be the most reasonable meaning. You could imagine that jabbing and nabbing is a way to get it cornered (or singled out) in order to capture him (grab 'em). As for @CarSmack's question, I see what you mean. Still, dlab maybe a nonsense word but tab isn't.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the writer of the song chose a random word that rhymed and might vaguely fit in the situation (you could imagine that it means something like 'mark' or 'tag'). However, it's not meant to have any particular or specific meaning.